# Position of "gern"

Tags: word-order

> 1. Am Freitagabend spiele gern ich Gitarre.
> 2. Am Freitagabend spiele ich gern Gitarre.

I think the first sentence is correct because I learned to write *gern* next to the verb. Which sentence is more natural?

And if the subject is in the first position, how can I write it?

> Ich spiele gern Gitarre am Freitagabend.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Information structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_structure), again.  It all depends on where you put the focus of the utterance.

> Am Freitagabend spiele ich gern Gitarre.
>
> Ich spiele gern am Freitagabend Gitarre

These are equally neutral, but can be interpreted as focussing the object *Gitarre*, especially if you emphasize or contrast it (*Gitarre, nicht Bass*).

> Ich spiele gern Gitarre am Freitag Abend.

Also works fine, but is slightly more marked to focus on the time.  (As you can see, focussed parts tend to come last in a sentence.)

> Am Freitagabend spiele gern **ich** Gitarre.

Now, this is heavily marked.  It looks, on the first glance, ungrammatical to even native speakers, but it absoluty works in contexts where you focus *ich* for contrast.  In speech, you must (!) also stress the *ich*.  Example context -- imagine A is asking a gig of B's band:

> A: Spielt X morgen wieder Gitarre?
>
> B: Nein, am Freitagabend spiele gern **ich** Gitarre.  Er ist am Samstag wieder dran.

---

In addition, you may exceptionally use the syntax with some poetic license:

> Am Freitag spiel' gern ich Gitarre,
>
> und rauch' dazu ne feine Zigarre.

This is without focussing on *ich*, and just for the sake of the rhyme.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. 
I thought if am Freitag goes to the front of the sentence, 'am Freitag' is emphasized. I learned from my German teacher that Germans write more sentences in (Somthing+Verb+Subject) than in (Subject+Verb+Somthing). Is German mostly emphasized as it focuses on the last part of the sentence?

Comment: (Something+Verb+Subject) would be rather unusual, maybe you used the wrong term there.

Comment: But anyway: yes, the the "emphasized" parts are more likely put at the beginning or the end. You have do distinguish focus and topic, though, and topic tends to come at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Sentence 2 is correct. "gern" comes only after the predicate when the subject is before the predicate. The first sentence is no correct German.

Comment: In general, the subject usually comes immediately before or after the verb, especially when it's a pronoun. (I prefer to use "verb" instead of "predicate", though both are used in grammatical literature. I've seen "predicate" used with other meanings though, so I think "verb" is clearer.) I'm not sure that the first sentence is totally impossible, but it does sound very odd.

Comment: "The first sentence is no correct German." - are you sure about that? I perceive the first sentence as putting a lot of additional emphasis on "ich", meaning that it's the speaker who likes playing the guitar on Friday evenings, not someone else, but with that in mind, it sounds correct to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I disagree. I don't have time to look up the explanation, but the first sentence is definitely not correct grammar.

Comment: @Roland I mostly agree, but I think there is a place for the first sentence where it is used exactly that way: "Am Freitag Abend spiele gerne *ich* Gitarre (und nicht Annelise wie Du behauptest)" - usually then in an offended tone.

Comment: Ok, in fact the example of @planetmaker is valid but can be used *only* in the situation where you want to emphase on the subject, but it still feels strange and I would also prefer "spiele *ich* gern(e)" (with emphasis on the subject).

Comment: @Madjosz: That's exactly what I described in my comment.

Comment: @planetmaker I see. I don't think that works without the part in parentheses or an "aber" or similar modal particles.

Comment: @Roland yes-ish. Though I think it can be left out (and left lingering as a non-spoken thought or available from further context, known to all participants of the conversation)

Answer (score 0):

Also jede Information in jedem Staz hat eine bestimmte Position. Wenn es Anfang des Satzes gebracht werden, dann wird es hervorgehoben. Aslo es wird wichtiger als der Rest der anderen Information.

Die normale Ordnung:
Ich rief meine Mutter gestern wegen ihrer Krankheit besorgt an

1. Subjekt:Ich
2. Teil 1 des Verbs:rief
3. bestimmte Angaben: 3.1.(Akkusativobjekt:meine Mutter) 3.2.(Temporal: gestern) 3.3(Kausal: wegen...) 3.4.(Modal: besorgt) 3.5.(Lokal:hier gibt es nicht)
4. unbestimmte Angaben: hier gibt es nicht
5. präpositionale Objekte
6. Teil 2 des Verbs: an

In der Regel können wir mit irgendeinem Teil beginnen, der erste Teil des verbs  folgt, und danach der Subjekt, und dann alle anderen Angaben in der entsprechenden Ordnung

Meine Mutter rief ich meine Mutter...
Gestern rief ich meine Mutter...
Wegen ihrer Krankheit rief ich meine Mutter....
Besorgt rief ich meine Mutter....
und so weiter.

Im Bezug auf Ihrem Satz,
Ich spiele am Freitagabend gern Gitarre. ( Ganz normal)

Am Freitagabend spiele ich gern Gitarre.( Wann ist dir die Wichtigste Sache)

Gern spiele ich am Freitagabend Gitarre. ( Die Intensität oder Modalität ist dir am Wichtigsten)

Aber mit Gitarre zu beginnen wäre es Falsch. Weil es wird als zwieter Teil des Verbs "spielen" betrachtet und es kommt nie vor dem ersten Teil https://mein-deutschbuch.de/angaben.html

Comment: _Gitarre spiele ich morgen gern_ ist überhaupt nicht falsch. Und man kann separierbare präfixe sehr wohl vor das Verb setzen: _Auf setze ich den Helm gerne, ab aber nicht_.

Comment: @phipsgabler
das gilt nur wenn das Hauptverb im Infinitiv oder Partizip 2
z.B. 
Anrufen wird ich dich heute Abend.
Eingeschlafen bin ich nicht.
https://deutschegrammatik20.de/wortposition/verb-position1/
wenn du noch anderer Meinung bist
kannst du diese Sätze umformulieren, sodass du mit dem Verb beginnt
(Ich bin Auto gefahren, Ich habe das Auto gefahren)

Ich freue mich gerne, wenn du auf einen Artikel oder so was, dass ihre Worte unterstützt, verweist

Comment: Außer meiner muttersprachlichen Intuition kann ich wenig bieten. Helbig/Buscha schreibt nur, dass "die Trennung (und Nachstellung) nur bei den _finiten Verbformen_ und bei diesen nur, wenn sie in _Zweitstellung_ oder in _Erststellung_ im Satz gebraucht werden [erfolgt]" (_Deutsche Grammatik_, Kap. 11.1). Aber das schließt _Auf setze ich den Helm gern_ eben nicht aus.

Comment: Und mit echten Komposita ist das Ganze unzweifelhaft möglich. Man braucht nur _Gitarre_ als Objekt auffassen, das man jedenfalls linksversetzen kann (_Den Baum säge ich heute, Gitarre spiele ich morgen_.)